# How to use shortcodes inside metaboxes in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom metabox using [this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Examples). When the admin-user enters a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) in my metabox, the shortcode displays on my front-end as plain text such as:

> [menu]

How can I make sure WordPress parses the shortcode so an actual menu is outputted?

I'm using this in my page.php template to display the contents of my custom metabox:

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_my_custom_meta_value_key', true );
```

Comment: You should look at the docs for [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

Comment: How would I use this?

Comment: Thanks, would you mind posting that as an answer. I can then give you some credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) provided by WordPress. This can be used to manually search through the given string for shortcodes.

According to docs for [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode):

> Searches content for shortcodes and filters shortcodes through their hooks.

This is how you can do it:

```
$shortcode = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_my_custom_meta_value_key', true );

echo do_shortcode($shortcode);
```